# Visualisation with GradCam from Monai expects larger input image

Tags: pytorch

I want to visualize the crucial parts which were important for the classification in healthy and ill with GradCAM for 3D MRI images.

Therefore, I use

> ```
> cam = GradCAM(nn_module=densenet, target_layers="class_layers.relu") 
> result = cam(x=torch.rand((1, 1, 7, 7, 7)))
> ```

where my densenet is defined as:

> self.densenet = densenet.densenet121(spatial_dims=3, in_channels=1,
> out_channels=1)

this throws the error:

> RuntimeError: input image (T: 1 H: 1 W: 1) smaller than kernel size
> (kT: 2 kH: 2 kW: 2)

Raising H,W,D to 30

> ```
> result = cam(x=torch.rand((1, 1, 30, 30, 30)))
> ```

leads to

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>
> File
> "/var/folders/79/z7g43_0x08g2yj7w6lb_j5280000gn/T/ipykernel_3133/4028907207.py",
> line 1, in 
> result = cam(x=torch.rand((64, 1, 30, 30, 30)))    #result mri image nehmen
>
> File
> "/Users/Wu/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/monai/visualize/class_activation_maps.py",
> line 380, in **call**
> acti_map = self.compute_map(x, class_idx=class_idx, retain_graph=retain_graph, layer_idx=layer_idx)
>
> File
> "/Users/Wu/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/monai/visualize/class_activation_maps.py",
> line 360, in compute_map
> _, acti, grad = self.nn_module(x, class_idx=class_idx, retain_graph=retain_graph)
>
> File
> "/Users/Wu/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/monai/visualize/class_activation_maps.py",
> line 135, in **call**
> acti = tuple(self.activations[layer] for layer in self.target_layers)
>
> File
> "/Users/Wu/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/monai/visualize/class_activation_maps.py",
> line 135, in 
> acti = tuple(self.activations[layer] for layer in self.target_layers)
>
> KeyError: 'class_layers.relu'

And using my own densenet class:

> ```
> #!/usr/bin/env python3
> # -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
> """
> Created on Tue Mar  8 23:23:24 2022
>
> @author: Wu
> """
>
> ###methods from pytorch lightening
>
>
> import torch
> import pytorch_lightning as pl
> from sklearn.metrics import accuracy_score, recall_score, precision_score, f1_score
> import torch.nn.functional as F
> from torch import nn
> import monai.networks.nets.densenet as densenet
> import pycm
> import numpy as np
>
>
> class DenseNet(pl.LightningModule):
>     def __init__(self, learning_rate=1e-4):
>         super().__init__()
>         self.densenet = densenet.densenet121(spatial_dims=3, in_channels=1, out_channels=1)
>         self.learning_rate = learning_rate
>         self.class_loss = torch.nn.BCEWithLogitsLoss(reduction='mean') #binarycorssentropy loss
> ```
>
> bceloss
> print('1')
>
> ```
>     def forward(self, x):
>
>         logits = self.densenet(x)
>
>         print('2')
>
>         #float(logits.float())
>         #logits = logits.float()
>         print(logits.dtype)
>
>         return logits
>
>     def configure_optimizers(self):
>         print('3')
>
>         optimizer = torch.optim.Adam(self.parameters(), lr=self.learning_rate)
>         return optimizer
>
>     def on_train_epoch_start(self):
>         print('4')
>
>         self.train_predictions = []
>         self.train_labels = []
>         
>         
>     def training_step(self, batch, batch_idx):
>         print('5')
>
>         mri, y  = batch['mri'], batch['label']
>         #y = y.type_as(logits)
>         #float(y.float())
>         y = y.float()
>         print (y.dtype)
>         logits = self(mri)
>         #float(logits.float())
>         logits = logits.float()
>         y_hat = (logits >= 0).float()
>         class_loss = self.class_loss(logits, y.unsqueeze(0))        
>         self.log('loss/train', class_loss, on_step=True, on_epoch=True, prog_bar=True, logger=True)
>         self.train_predictions.extend(y_hat.tolist())
>         self.train_labels.extend(y.tolist())
>         return class_loss
>
>     def on_train_epoch_end(self, outputs):
>         print('6')
>
>         cm = pycm.ConfusionMatrix(actual_vector=self.train_labels, predict_vector=self.train_predictions)
>         self.log('accuracy/train', cm.Overall_ACC)
>         if cm.F1_Macro is not 'None':
>             self.log('f1_macro/train', cm.F1_Macro)
>         if cm.F1_Micro is not 'None':
>             self.log('f1_micro/train', cm.F1_Micro)
>         #prit(cm)
>
>     def on_validation_epoch_start(self):
>         print('7')
>
>         self.predictions = []
>         self.labels = []
>
>     def validation_step(self, batch, batch_idx):
>         print('8')
>
>         mri, y = batch['mri'], batch['label']
>         logits = self(mri)
>         float(y.float())
>         y = y.float()
>         print (y.dtype)
>         float(logits.float())
>         logits = logits.float()
>         
>         y_hat = (logits >= 0).float()
>         class_loss = self.class_loss(logits, y.unsqueeze(0))
>         self.log(f'loss/valid', class_loss, on_step=True, on_epoch=True, prog_bar=True, logger=True)
>         self.predictions.extend(y_hat.tolist())
>         self.labels.extend(y.tolist())
>
>     def on_validation_epoch_end(self):
>         print('9')
>
>         cm = pycm.ConfusionMatrix(actual_vector=self.labels, predict_vector=self.predictions)
>         self.log('accuracy/valid', cm.Overall_ACC)
>         if cm.F1_Macro is not 'None':
>             self.log('f1_macro/valid', cm.F1_Macro)
>         if cm.F1_Micro is not 'None':
>             self.log('f1_micro/valid', cm.F1_Micro)
>
>         #print(cm)
> ```

The output of densenet.state_dict().keys() is
So there is no class_layers.relu.
What would be the equivalent layer?

densenet.state_dict().keys()
.
.
.
.

> 'densenet.features.denseblock4.denselayer1.layers.norm1.num_batches_tracked',
> 'densenet.features.denseblock4.denselayer1.layers.conv1.weight',
> 'densenet.features.denseblock4.denselayer1.layers.norm2.weight',
> 'densenet.features.denseblock4.denselayer1.layers.norm2.bias',
> 'densenet.features.denseblock4.denselayer1.layers.norm2.running_mean',
> 'densenet.features.denseblock4.denselayer1.layers.norm2.running_var',
> 'densenet.features.denseblock4.denselayer1.layers.norm2.num_batches_tracked',
> 'densenet.features.denseblock4.denselayer1.layers.conv2.weight',
> 'densenet.features.denseblock4.denselayer2.layers.norm1.weight',
> 'densenet.features.denseblock4.denselayer2.layers.norm1.bias',
> 'densenet.features.denseblock4.denselayer2.layers.norm1.running_mean',
> 'densenet.features.denseblock4.denselayer2.layers.norm1.running_var',
> 'densenet.features.denseblock4.denselayer2.layers.norm1.num_batches_tracked',
> 'densenet.features.denseblock4.denselayer2.layers.conv1.weight',
> 'densenet.features.denseblock4.denselayer2.layers.norm2.weight',
> 'densenet.features.denseblock4.denselayer2.layers.norm2.bias',
> 'densenet.features.denseblock4.denselayer2.layers.norm2.running_mean',
> 'densenet.features.denseblock4.denselayer2.layers.norm2.running_var',
> 'densenet.features.denseblock4.denselayer2.layers.norm2.num_batches_tracked',
> 'densenet.features.denseblock4.denselayer2.layers.conv2.weight',
> 'densenet.features.denseblock4.denselayer3.layers.norm1.weight',
> 'densenet.features.denseblock4.denselayer3.layers.norm1.bias',
> 'densenet.features.denseblock4.denselayer3.layers.norm1.running_mean',
> 'densenet.features.denseblock4.denselayer3.layers.norm1.running_var',
> 'densenet.features.denseblock4.denselayer3.layers.norm1.num_batches_tracked',
> 'densenet.features.denseblock4.denselayer3.layers.conv1.weight',
> 'densenet.features.denseblock4.denselayer3.layers.norm2.weight',
> 'densenet.features.denseblock4.denselayer3.layers.norm2.bias',
> 'densenet.features.denseblock4.denselayer3.layers.norm2.running_mean',
> 'densenet.features.denseblock4.denselayer3.layers.norm2.running_var',
> 'densenet.features.denseblock4.denselayer3.layers.norm2.num_batches_tracked',
> 'densenet.features.denseblock4.denselayer3.layers.conv2.weight',
> 'densenet.features.denseblock4.denselayer4.layers.norm1.weight',
> 'densenet.features.denseblock4.denselayer4.layers.norm1.bias',
> 'densenet.features.denseblock4.denselayer4.layers.norm1.running_mean',
> 'densenet.features.denseblock4.denselayer4.layers.norm1.running_var',
> 'densenet.features.denseblock4.denselayer4.layers.norm1.num_batches_tracked',
> 'densenet.features.denseblock4.denselayer4.layers.conv1.weight',
> 'densenet.features.denseblock4.denselayer4.layers.norm2.weight',
> 'densenet.features.denseblock4.denselayer4.layers.norm2.bias',
> 'densenet.features.denseblock4.denselayer4.layers.norm2.running_mean',
> 'densenet.features.denseblock4.denselayer4.layers.norm2.running_var',
> 'densenet.features.denseblock4.denselayer4.layers.norm2.num_batches_tracked',
> 'densenet.features.denseblock4.denselayer4.layers.conv2.weight',
> 'densenet.features.denseblock4.denselayer5.layers.norm1.weight',
> 'densenet.features.denseblock4.denselayer5.layers.norm1.bias',
> 'densenet.features.denseblock4.denselayer5.layers.norm1.running_mean',
> 'densenet.features.denseblock4.denselayer5.layers.norm1.running_var',
> 'densenet.features.denseblock4.denselayer5.layers.norm1.num_batches_tracked',
> 'densenet.features.denseblock4.denselayer5.layers.conv1.weight',
> 'densenet.features.denseblock4.denselayer5.layers.norm2.weight',
> 'densenet.features.denseblock4.denselayer5.layers.norm2.bias',
> 'densenet.features.denseblock4.denselayer5.layers.norm2.running_mean',
> 'densenet.features.denseblock4.denselayer5.layers.norm2.running_var',
> 'densenet.features.denseblock4.denselayer5.layers.norm2.num_batches_tracked',
> 'densenet.features.denseblock4.denselayer5.layers.conv2.weight',
> 'densenet.features.denseblock4.denselayer6.layers.norm1.weight',
> 'densenet.features.denseblock4.denselayer6.layers.norm1.bias',
> 'densenet.features.denseblock4.denselayer6.layers.norm1.running_mean',
> 'densenet.features.denseblock4.denselayer6.layers.norm1.running_var',
> 'densenet.features.denseblock4.denselayer6.layers.norm1.num_batches_tracked',
> 'densenet.features.denseblock4.denselayer6.layers.conv1.weight',
> 'densenet.features.denseblock4.denselayer6.layers.norm2.weight',
> 'densenet.features.denseblock4.denselayer6.layers.norm2.bias',
> 'densenet.features.denseblock4.denselayer6.layers.norm2.running_mean',
> 'densenet.features.denseblock4.denselayer6.layers.norm2.running_var',
> 'densenet.features.denseblock4.denselayer6.layers.norm2.num_batches_tracked',
> 'densenet.features.denseblock4.denselayer6.layers.conv2.weight',
> 'densenet.features.denseblock4.denselayer7.layers.norm1.weight',
> 'densenet.features.denseblock4.denselayer7.layers.norm1.bias',
> 'densenet.features.denseblock4.denselayer7.layers.norm1.running_mean',
> 'densenet.features.denseblock4.denselayer7.layers.norm1.running_var',
> 'densenet.features.denseblock4.denselayer7.layers.norm1.num_batches_tracked',
> 'densenet.features.denseblock4.denselayer7.layers.conv1.weight',
> 'densenet.features.denseblock4.denselayer7.layers.norm2.weight',
> 'densenet.features.denseblock4.denselayer7.layers.norm2.bias',
> 'densenet.features.denseblock4.denselayer7.layers.norm2.running_mean',
> 'densenet.features.denseblock4.denselayer7.layers.norm2.running_var',
> 'densenet.features.denseblock4.denselayer7.layers.norm2.num_batches_tracked',
> 'densenet.features.denseblock4.denselayer7.layers.conv2.weight',
> 'densenet.features.denseblock4.denselayer8.layers.norm1.weight',
> 'densenet.features.denseblock4.denselayer8.layers.norm1.bias',
> 'densenet.features.denseblock4.denselayer8.layers.norm1.running_mean',
> 'densenet.features.denseblock4.denselayer8.layers.norm1.running_var',
> 'densenet.features.denseblock4.denselayer8.layers.norm1.num_batches_tracked',
> 'densenet.features.denseblock4.denselayer8.layers.conv1.weight',
> 'densenet.features.denseblock4.denselayer8.layers.norm2.weight',
> 'densenet.features.denseblock4.denselayer8.layers.norm2.bias',
> 'densenet.features.denseblock4.denselayer8.layers.norm2.running_mean',
> 'densenet.features.denseblock4.denselayer8.layers.norm2.running_var',
> 'densenet.features.denseblock4.denselayer8.layers.norm2.num_batches_tracked',
> 'densenet.features.denseblock4.denselayer8.layers.conv2.weight',
> 'densenet.features.denseblock4.denselayer9.layers.norm1.weight',
> 'densenet.features.denseblock4.denselayer9.layers.norm1.bias',
> 'densenet.features.denseblock4.denselayer9.layers.norm1.running_mean',
> 'densenet.features.denseblock4.denselayer9.layers.norm1.running_var',
> 'densenet.features.denseblock4.denselayer9.layers.norm1.num_batches_tracked',
> 'densenet.features.denseblock4.denselayer9.layers.conv1.weight',
> 'densenet.features.denseblock4.denselayer9.layers.norm2.weight',
> 'densenet.features.denseblock4.denselayer9.layers.norm2.bias',
> 'densenet.features.denseblock4.denselayer9.layers.norm2.running_mean',
> 'densenet.features.denseblock4.denselayer9.layers.norm2.running_var',
> 'densenet.features.denseblock4.denselayer9.layers.norm2.num_batches_tracked',
> 'densenet.features.denseblock4.denselayer9.layers.conv2.weight',
> 'densenet.features.denseblock4.denselayer10.layers.norm1.weight',
> 'densenet.features.denseblock4.denselayer10.layers.norm1.bias',
> 'densenet.features.denseblock4.denselayer10.layers.norm1.running_mean',
> 'densenet.features.denseblock4.denselayer10.layers.norm1.running_var',
> 'densenet.features.denseblock4.denselayer10.layers.norm1.num_batches_tracked',
> 'densenet.features.denseblock4.denselayer10.layers.conv1.weight',
> 'densenet.features.denseblock4.denselayer10.layers.norm2.weight',
> 'densenet.features.denseblock4.denselayer10.layers.norm2.bias',
> 'densenet.features.denseblock4.denselayer10.layers.norm2.running_mean',
> 'densenet.features.denseblock4.denselayer10.layers.norm2.running_var',
> 'densenet.features.denseblock4.denselayer10.layers.norm2.num_batches_tracked',
> 'densenet.features.denseblock4.denselayer10.layers.conv2.weight',
> 'densenet.features.denseblock4.denselayer11.layers.norm1.weight',
> 'densenet.features.denseblock4.denselayer11.layers.norm1.bias',
> 'densenet.features.denseblock4.denselayer11.layers.norm1.running_mean',
> 'densenet.features.denseblock4.denselayer11.layers.norm1.running_var',
> 'densenet.features.denseblock4.denselayer11.layers.norm1.num_batches_tracked',
> 'densenet.features.denseblock4.denselayer11.layers.conv1.weight',
> 'densenet.features.denseblock4.denselayer11.layers.norm2.weight',
> 'densenet.features.denseblock4.denselayer11.layers.norm2.bias',
> 'densenet.features.denseblock4.denselayer11.layers.norm2.running_mean',
> 'densenet.features.denseblock4.denselayer11.layers.norm2.running_var',
> 'densenet.features.denseblock4.denselayer11.layers.norm2.num_batches_tracked',
> 'densenet.features.denseblock4.denselayer11.layers.conv2.weight',
> 'densenet.features.denseblock4.denselayer12.layers.norm1.weight',
> 'densenet.features.denseblock4.denselayer12.layers.norm1.bias',
> 'densenet.features.denseblock4.denselayer12.layers.norm1.running_mean',
> 'densenet.features.denseblock4.denselayer12.layers.norm1.running_var',
> 'densenet.features.denseblock4.denselayer12.layers.norm1.num_batches_tracked',
> 'densenet.features.denseblock4.denselayer12.layers.conv1.weight',
> 'densenet.features.denseblock4.denselayer12.layers.norm2.weight',
> 'densenet.features.denseblock4.denselayer12.layers.norm2.bias',
> 'densenet.features.denseblock4.denselayer12.layers.norm2.running_mean',
> 'densenet.features.denseblock4.denselayer12.layers.norm2.running_var',
> 'densenet.features.denseblock4.denselayer12.layers.norm2.num_batches_tracked',
> 'densenet.features.denseblock4.denselayer12.layers.conv2.weight',
> 'densenet.features.denseblock4.denselayer13.layers.norm1.weight',
> 'densenet.features.denseblock4.denselayer13.layers.norm1.bias',
> 'densenet.features.denseblock4.denselayer13.layers.norm1.running_mean',
> 'densenet.features.denseblock4.denselayer13.layers.norm1.running_var',
> 'densenet.features.denseblock4.denselayer13.layers.norm1.num_batches_tracked',
> 'densenet.features.denseblock4.denselayer13.layers.conv1.weight',
> 'densenet.features.denseblock4.denselayer13.layers.norm2.weight',
> 'densenet.features.denseblock4.denselayer13.layers.norm2.bias',
> 'densenet.features.denseblock4.denselayer13.layers.norm2.running_mean',
> 'densenet.features.denseblock4.denselayer13.layers.norm2.running_var',
> 'densenet.features.denseblock4.denselayer13.layers.norm2.num_batches_tracked',
> 'densenet.features.denseblock4.denselayer13.layers.conv2.weight',
> 'densenet.features.denseblock4.denselayer14.layers.norm1.weight',
> 'densenet.features.denseblock4.denselayer14.layers.norm1.bias',
> 'densenet.features.denseblock4.denselayer14.layers.norm1.running_mean',
> 'densenet.features.denseblock4.denselayer14.layers.norm1.running_var',
> 'densenet.features.denseblock4.denselayer14.layers.norm1.num_batches_tracked',
> 'densenet.features.denseblock4.denselayer14.layers.conv1.weight',
> 'densenet.features.denseblock4.denselayer14.layers.norm2.weight',
> 'densenet.features.denseblock4.denselayer14.layers.norm2.bias',
> 'densenet.features.denseblock4.denselayer14.layers.norm2.running_mean',
> 'densenet.features.denseblock4.denselayer14.layers.norm2.running_var',
> 'densenet.features.denseblock4.denselayer14.layers.norm2.num_batches_tracked',
> 'densenet.features.denseblock4.denselayer14.layers.conv2.weight',
> 'densenet.features.denseblock4.denselayer15.layers.norm1.weight',
> 'densenet.features.denseblock4.denselayer15.layers.norm1.bias',
> 'densenet.features.denseblock4.denselayer15.layers.norm1.running_mean',
> 'densenet.features.denseblock4.denselayer15.layers.norm1.running_var',
> 'densenet.features.denseblock4.denselayer15.layers.norm1.num_batches_tracked',
> 'densenet.features.denseblock4.denselayer15.layers.conv1.weight',
> 'densenet.features.denseblock4.denselayer15.layers.norm2.weight',
> 'densenet.features.denseblock4.denselayer15.layers.norm2.bias',
> 'densenet.features.denseblock4.denselayer15.layers.norm2.running_mean',
> 'densenet.features.denseblock4.denselayer15.layers.norm2.running_var',
> 'densenet.features.denseblock4.denselayer15.layers.norm2.num_batches_tracked',
> 'densenet.features.denseblock4.denselayer15.layers.conv2.weight',
> 'densenet.features.denseblock4.denselayer16.layers.norm1.weight',
> 'densenet.features.denseblock4.denselayer16.layers.norm1.bias',
> 'densenet.features.denseblock4.denselayer16.layers.norm1.running_mean',
> 'densenet.features.denseblock4.denselayer16.layers.norm1.running_var',
> 'densenet.features.denseblock4.denselayer16.layers.norm1.num_batches_tracked',
> 'densenet.features.denseblock4.denselayer16.layers.conv1.weight',
> 'densenet.features.denseblock4.denselayer16.layers.norm2.weight',
> 'densenet.features.denseblock4.denselayer16.layers.norm2.bias',
> 'densenet.features.denseblock4.denselayer16.layers.norm2.running_mean',
> 'densenet.features.denseblock4.denselayer16.layers.norm2.running_var',
> 'densenet.features.denseblock4.denselayer16.layers.norm2.num_batches_tracked',
> 'densenet.features.denseblock4.denselayer16.layers.conv2.weight',
> 'densenet.features.norm5.weight', 'densenet.features.norm5.bias',
> 'densenet.features.norm5.running_mean',
> 'densenet.features.norm5.running_var',
> 'densenet.features.norm5.num_batches_tracked',
> 'densenet.class_layers.out.weight', 'densenet.class_layers.out.bias'])

Answer (score 0):

You may need to pay attention to the usage of `import`, the following code should help you.

```
import torch
from monai.networks.nets import DenseNet121
from monai.visualize import GradCAM

model = DenseNet121(spatial_dims=3, in_channels=1, out_channels=1)
cam = GradCAM(nn_module=model, target_layers="class_layers.relu") 
result = cam(x=torch.rand(1, 1, 64, 64, 64))
```

Comment: I updated my question: I defined my own densenet class, that is why I used     densenet = DenseNet(learning_rate=hparams.learning_rate)

Comment: The first error is obviously that the size is too small for the model to calculate. The second error you may need to use `model.state_dict().keys()` to check if your model has the keys(`class_layers.relu`) you specified.

Comment: Yes, great, thats what I was looking for and class_layers.relu does not exist. What would be the equivalent layer?

Comment: My fault, `keys()` will only show the included weights, here should use `print(model)` to find the last layer.

Comment: Then densenet.state_dict().print(densenet)? leads to AttributeError: 'collections.OrderedDict' object has no attribute 'print'

Comment: According to your code, you need to use this `self.densenet`.

Comment: self.densenet.state_dict().print(densenet)?

Comment: just `print(self.densenet)`

Comment: it gives me in the end:

      (norm5): BatchNorm3d(1024, eps=1e-05, momentum=0.1, affine=True, track_running_stats=True)
    )
    (class_layers): Sequential(
      (relu): ReLU(inplace=True)
      (pool): AdaptiveAvgPool3d(output_size=1)
      (flatten): Flatten(start_dim=1, end_dim=-1)
      (out): Linear(in_features=1024, out_features=1, bias=True)
    )
  )
  (class_loss): BCEWithLogitsLoss()
)

Would that be the class_layers.relu

Comment: This is very strange, in your log message, `class_layers.relu` does exist, you can try this `target_layers="densenet.class_layers.relu"`

Comment: great, I do not get an error anymore when typing in 
 result = cam(x=torch.rand((1, 1, 64, 64, 64)))
How would I visualize now the calculated result in the end to get a color map of which parts of the image is important and which not?